# Take/assign SQL JSON data value on certain key based on another key

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have two SQL tables, one refer to a list of questions and the other is for the answers. The answer table looks like this:

```
Question_ID      answer_id
    1              ["A"]
    2              ["B"]
    3            ["A", "B"]
```

For the question table, it looks like this:

```
Question_ID                                   choices_value
    1           {"multiple_choices:"[{"id":"A", "name":"Italy"},{id:"B", "name":"Germany"}]}
    2            {"multiple_choices:"[{"id":"A", "name":"Left"},{id:"B", "name":"Right"}]}
    3             {"multiple_choices:"[{"id":"A", "name":"Red"},{id:"B", "name":"Green"}]}
```

My question is, how do I take/assign the value in the "name" key on choices_value based on both question_ID and key from answer_id?

edited:

additional info:

- I use MySQL 8.0

Comment: We need to know your exact SQL vendor (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) in order to answer this question.

Comment: I use MySQL if this help

Comment: also version matters pre8.0 or 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to parse your json to tabular format. Then join both tables.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c77f1ce1a90f1a015884463643cd642c).

```
with questions as (
  select 1 as question_id
    , '{"multiple_choices":[{"id":"A", "name":"Italy"},{"id":"B", "name":"Germany"}]}' as jsval
  union all 
  select 2
    , '{"multiple_choices":[{"id":"A", "name":"Left"},{"id":"B", "name":"Right"}]}'
  union all
  select 3
    , '{"multiple_choices":[{"id":"A", "name":"Red"},{"id":"B", "name":"Green"}]}'
)
, answers as (
  select 1  as question_id, '["A"]' as answer       
  union all
  select 2  as question_id, '["B"]' as answer
  union all
  select 3  as question_id, '["A", "B"]' as answer
)
, q_avail_ans as (
  select q.question_id, q_a.*
  from questions as q,
    json_table(q.jsval,
      '$."multiple_choices"[*]'
      columns (
        ans_id varchar(100) path '$."id"',
        ans_name varchar(100) path '$."name"'
      )
    ) as q_a
)
, q_answered_ans as (
  select a.question_id,
    a_a.*
  from answers as a,
    json_table(a.answer,
      '$[*]'
      columns (
        ans varchar(100) path '$'
      )
    ) as a_a
)
select qa.*
  , aa.ans
from q_avail_ans as qa
  left join q_answered_ans as aa
    on qa.question_id = aa.question_id
      and qa.ans_id = aa.ans
```